# Position dependent audio playback for multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I've been designing an html/js based media player whose goal is to give the user some simple playback and region movement functionality found in common DAW's. My ui is comprised of 5 individual tracks and playback controls. By using wavesurfer.js I've been able to successfully create any number of wavesurfer instances/regions inside these tracks, drag and position them anywhere I'd like, and play selected audio files.

In my experimentation with wavesurfer.js, I've found that each instance has its own playhead which indicates the current playback position of the selected audio file and allows the user to navigate playback within that instance.

**My issue is that I would also like to have a single "master" playhead which is not contained within any particular instance and am unsure how to approach this.**

While there are complex web DAW's out there, I haven't found a source that really helps me understand how to handle audio playback in the way I need..but I know it's been done before. I've read through the webaudio API and wavesurfer.js documentation and unless there's something I'm missing within wavesurfer's capabilities, I'm assuming I need to work with webaudio API to achieve this result - would I start by defining a new AudioContext object comprised of all of the present audio files as AudioNodes?

**With multiple audio files/wavesurfer instances whose playback must be dependent on their user-determined positions within the context of the whole track workspace, how would I approach handling audio playback?**

Thanks for any insight, I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have tagged JavaScript and you have not posted any line of code so that we can see what you have done and where you have a problem. You need to include some code as a basis to start otherwise you will not get any help

Comment: You could use a higher scoped var which you don't scope off within your Constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with for example 5 trackouts, you need to be aware that if you load them into audiobuffers (or audionodes like you call em) they will actually become pretty big concerning the RAM amount if they are longer. So perhaps you can reach your goal if you use five audio elements and set their state and position, though these audio elements can not that easily be accessed by filters and effects and such (Convolver etc.). It really depends on your setup and a prototype shouldn't be too hard to program, so if you are really passionate about it you can make both.

At my website 1ln.de you can load mp3 files (different) in the audio positions and RAM gets up to 30 % of 8 GB if you load 5 mp3 in memory. But RAM is much faster then streaming audio. Because the audio elements need to buffer their contents first and you can't handle and manipulate them as easy as audio buffers.

It really depends on the comlexity of your tool and what you want to achieve.

For professional usage and fast playback i would recommend you playing with audio buffers. It will take some time to decode the audio files first though. But you can handle when buffering is finished.

Hopefully I got your question right.

If you want to program a DAW feel free to say hi for some help.